# Add value from Php array and increment next

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array which holds a list of colours.

```
<?php $colours = array("pink", "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "grey", "cyan"); ?>
```

I then have a Wordpress loop running to display posts. Is there a way that each post would have a value taken from the array and then the one after would have the other value?

For example:

First post: `<div class="pink"></div>`

Second post: `<div class="red"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's a loop like this

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post">


    <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

you can simply add a counter like this

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="<?php echo $colours[$count % count($colours)]; ?>">
<?php $count++; ?>

<!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->

<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($colours as $color) {
?>
<div class="<?php echo $color; ?>"> </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi, this would return a list of divs with the different colours. What i need to do is for each Wordpress post to add a colour. Does that make sense?
 Sorry, i should've been more precise in my question.

Comment: for that i think you can take different varibles and put different color for odd and even post , code will be not feasible but you may achive your goals

Answer (score 0):

You can make a decision over key. Check it if odd then it will go to the 1st div else even it will go to the 2nd div. Wish it helps.